# Why is Calendar value different?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, containskey

I have to count the number of times depending on year, month, day, hour, minute.(second is unified to zero, I don't need second)

I chose HashMap as the data structure.

```java
HashMap<Calendar,Integer> arr_time;
```

If there are same time(year,month,day,hour,minute) already, I want to increase the Integer, or add a new time(year,month,day,hour,minute).

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(mYear,mMonth,mDay,mHour,mMinute,0);
if(arr_time.containsKey(calendar)){
  // increase Integer value
  // ++1;
}else{
  // add new time 
  // arr_time.put(calendar,1);
}
```

I thought it would recognize the same calendar if year, month, day, hour, and minute were the same.
But it was not.

What is the problem?

I didn't use "Date".
It's because, Android Devloper said like this.

> Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec) 
>   This constructor was deprecated in API level 1. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed, which is probably causing your trouble, and is also long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Never use `Calendar`

The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted by the *java.time* classes years ago, specifically `ZonedDateTime`.

## Time zone

You are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. A date and time-of-day have no real meaning until you provide the context of time zone (or offset-from-UTC).  For example, noon is `Europe/Paris` is much later than noon in `Asia/Tokyo` and much earlier than noon in `America/Montreal`.

### `ZonedDateTime`

Represent a date and time-of-day with time zone with the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

### `ZoneID`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

### `truncatedTo`

If you want to set the second and fractional second both to zero, truncate to the minute.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;  // Set the whole second and the fractional second both to zero.
```

### `LocalDateTime`

If, for your counting purposes, you want to consider only the date with time-of-day while ignoring the time zone, extract a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). A `LocalDateTime` is simply a date with time-of-day, and lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime() ;
```

### `Map` ➙ `SortedMap` ➙ `TreeMap`

With a `LocalDateTime` in hand, you can do your counting. Make a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) where the key is a `LocalDateTime`, and the value is an `Integer`.

I imagine you will care about the sorted order of the date-time keys, so use a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html). A [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) is one such implementation.

```
SortedMap< LocalDateTime , Integer > map = new TreeMap() ;
```

For each `LocalDateTime`, retrieve an `Integer` object from the `Map`. Increment the number count, and replace the old `Integer` object with a new one.

Using a `Map` has been covered many hundreds, if not thousands, of times already on Stack Overflow. So search if you need more discussion and examples of that.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: thank you for your comment!!!
I have additional question. 

You said "map and stack overflow". 
After that process, if I want next process, I have to sort map by "year&month&day" or "hour&minute" or "value(integer)".
Can I use sortedmap in this case? 

Any map(sorted, hashmap, treemap) has stack overflow?

Comment: Sorting has been covered a zillion times on Stack Overflow. Search for `compareTo`, [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), and [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: @현도연 The `SortedMap` shown in the answer may be advantageous for you in that case, but it depends on requirements that are not fully clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> arr_time = new HashMap<>();
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Antarctica/Vostok");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(zone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        arr_time.compute(now, (ldt, oldCount) -> oldCount == null ? Integer.valueOf(1) : oldCount + 1);

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(103);
    }
    System.out.println(arr_time);
```

When I ran the code just now, I got:

> {2019-02-20T13:42=10}

I recorded 10 times, sleeping in between to make sure they were not exactly the same. But because I truncated each to whole minutes, they all ended up being `2019-02-20T13:42` and were counted together.

To create a `LocalDateTime` from `int` variables:

```
    int mYear = 2019;
    int mMonth = Calendar.JANUARY;
    int mDay = 31;
    int mHour = 23;
    int mMinute = 45;
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(mYear, mMonth + 1, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

> 2019-01-31T23:45

Since you used `mMonth` with `Calendar`, I assumed it was 0-based. `LocalDateTime` numbers months from 1, just like humans do, so I needed to add 1.

### What went wrong in your code?

`calendar.set(mYear,mMonth,mDay,mHour,mMinute,0)` sets year, month, day, hour, minute and second *but is not setting the milliseconds*. Since each `Calendar` object is created with the current time, the milliseconds will most often be different, so the even though you set the same values, the `Calendar` objects are still not equal.

That behaviour of the 6-arg `set` method surprises many and is just a minor point among the many points where the class is poorly designed. You shouldn’t use it. We’ve got java.time since 2014, so there’s really no reason to.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.